# Sqlite PreparedStatement not returning ResultSet despite query working elsewhere

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am having an issue in which I am receiving an empty `ResultSet` for a query that I know works with the given database.

This database (truncated and anonymised) is as follows:

```
-- Table: places
CREATE TABLE places (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, venue_id INTEGER, timestamp INTEGER, venue_name TEXT);
INSERT INTO places (id, venue_id, timestamp, venue_name) VALUES (1, 1, 1533231909000, 'Place 1');
INSERT INTO places (id, venue_id, timestamp, venue_name) VALUES (2, 2, 1533231909000, 'Place 2');
INSERT INTO places (id, venue_id, timestamp, venue_name) VALUES (3, 1, 1533231911000, 'Place 1');
INSERT INTO places (id, venue_id, timestamp, venue_name) VALUES (4, 1, 1533232901300, 'Place 1');
INSERT INTO places (id, venue_id, timestamp, venue_name) VALUES (5, 2, 1533233301300, 'Place 2');
INSERT INTO places (id, venue_id, timestamp, venue_name) VALUES (6, 3, 1533245000000, 'Place 3');
-- Table: opening_times
CREATE TABLE opening_times (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, venue_id INTEGER, timestamp INTEGER);
INSERT INTO opening_times (id, venue_id, timestamp) VALUES (1, 1, 1546300836000);
INSERT INTO opening_times (id, venue_id, timestamp) VALUES (2, 2, 1546300840000);
INSERT INTO opening_times (id, venue_id, timestamp) VALUES (3, 1, 1546300840000);
INSERT INTO opening_times (id, venue_id, timestamp) VALUES (4, 1, 1533231911000);
INSERT INTO opening_times (id, venue_id, timestamp) VALUES (5, 1, 1533232011000);
INSERT INTO opening_times (id, venue_id, timestamp) VALUES (6, 3, 1533232011000);
INSERT INTO opening_times (id, venue_id, timestamp) VALUES (7, 2, 1533232011000);
```

My code is generating the following SQL command (albeit, not pretty-printed)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p.venue_name,
                q.changes
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 AS changes,
               venue_id,
               timestamp
        FROM   opening_times t
        GROUP  BY t.venue_id) q
       JOIN places p
         ON q.venue_id = p.venue_id
WHERE  q.changes > 0
       AND q.timestamp >= 0
       AND q.timestamp < 1633232011000
ORDER  BY q.changes DESC,
          p.venue_name ASC;
```

Using this query in an SQLite Database editor program (also executed in [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/752419/6) SQLFiddle) returns the correct results e.g.

```
| venue_name | changes |
|------------|---------|
|    Place 1 |       3 |
|    Place 2 |       1 |
```

However, my Java code is not getting these same results for the **same** database.

```java
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
connection.setAutoCommit(true);

String sql = "..."; // See above
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

while(resultSet.next()) {
   // Code here never executes at present as nothing is returned in the result set
}
```

I have ready numerous SO posts and as far as I can tell I followed the correct steps in order to get the data correctly. Other less complicated queries work just fine, it just seems this particular one fails to return data at present.

I am also using Java 8 and `org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc` version 3.25.2 to connect to the database if that should make any difference.

Comment: Please post the full code as it is with the sql query and any error handling  (try/catch) you  have

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that can consistently reproduce the issue using a SQLite in-memory database, including DDL (CREATE TABLE) and sample data (INSERT INTO)?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - The full code just has a standard try / catch. No exception is being thrown

Comment: @EdGeorge If there is no error thrown then the problem is in: `sql = "...";`. Maybe the string is not an exact copy of the original that works.

Comment: @GordThompson - Updated

Comment: @forpas I have printed out the SQL to the console and successfully run it within an SQLite editor.

Comment: Maybe try to call `getWarnings()` on your connection object to see if it gives you anything.

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson - I did try that and nothing was returned

Comment: Could not reproduce with (Xerial) sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.1.jar or sqlite-jdbc-3.25.2.jar. Repro code [here](https://pastebin.com/K2JtEj40) returns two rows, as does DBeaver running the same query.

Comment: Hi @GordThompson - changing the Xerial sqlite-jdbc version to 3.21.0.1 did the trick! I have no idea what the issue is with 3.25.2 for me

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same database? What happens if you use a simpler query? In any case, make sure your code is a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - As mentioned above, I am using _exactly_ the same database. It has now been resolved by simply reverting the sqlite-jdbc version to 3.21.0.1

Comment: Strange, 3.25.2 works fine for me both on Windows and Linux. (Are you on a Mac?) Still, good to hear that you got it working.

Comment: Yeah, @GordThompson - I am on OSX 10.14 - I will add an answer here and potentially look into raising a bug when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by reverting to `org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.21.0.1`

I experienced the issue on my OSX 10.14 machine, but the later version 3.25.2 seems to be working for other users on both on Windows and Linux.